# auto resize webpage html/css

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

Im currently trying to get my window in sharepoint to auto-resize when the user changes the size of their window. im using a web version of sharepoint at work. not allowed to use designer.

```
<style type="text/css">

#dgwrap {
    HEIGHT: 1000px; BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(PublishingImages/graybk.png); BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat-y; MARGIN-TOP: 75px; WIDTH: 1325px
}
.dgtopbox {
    FONT-SIZE: 9pt; HEIGHT: 200px; FLOAT: left; TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN-LEFT: 350px; MARGIN-TOP: 110px; WIDTH: 700px
}
#dgtopboxleft {
    HEIGHT: 50px; FLOAT: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 350px; MARGIN-TOP: 25px; WIDTH: 200px
}
#dgtopboxright {
    HEIGHT: 50px; FLOAT: right; MARGIN-TOP: 25px; WIDTH: 200px; MARGIN-RIGHT: 300px
}
#dgtopboxother {
    FLOAT: left; MARGIN-RIGHT: 25px
}
#otherbutton {
    HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(PublishingImages/otherbutton.png); BACKGROUND-REPEAT: no-repeat; MARGIN-TOP: 70px; DISPLAY: block; WIDTH: 160px
}
#clmbutton {
    BORDER-TOP: #838b8b 1pt solid; HEIGHT: 40px; BORDER-RIGHT: #838b8b 1pt solid; BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(PublishingImages/CLMbutton.png); BORDER-BOTTOM: #838b8b 1pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: #838b8b 1pt solid; DISPLAY: block
}
#clmbutton:hover {
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(/Operations/ProviderOperations/SpecialOps/PublishingImages/CLMbutton2.png)
}
#confbutton {
    BORDER-TOP: #838b8b 1pt solid; HEIGHT: 40px; BORDER-RIGHT: #838b8b 1pt solid; BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(/PublishingImages/CONFbutton.png); BORDER-BOTTOM: #838b8b 1pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: #838b8b 1pt solid; DISPLAY: block

}
#confbutton:hover {
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(/PublishingImages/CONFbutton2.png)
}
</style>


<div id="dgwrap">

<div id="dgtopboxleft"><a title="1box" id="CLMbutton" href="####.html"></a></div>
<div id="dgtopboxright"><a title="2box" id="CONFbutton" href="####.html"></a></div>
<div id="dgtopboxother"><a title="3box" id="otherbutton" href="####.html"></a></div>


<div class="dgtopbox">

<h3>Request Policy</h3>

<p style="text-align: left">1.text here.</p>
<p style="text-align: left">2.text.</p>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Use relative values (e.g. in ``%`` or ``em``) when sizing your elements, instead of using absolute values (``px`` and ``pt``).

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to make page responsive you should put all the values in %, give max-width and max-height instead of height and width, try to remove Display:Block as much as possible
Regards
Arjun

Comment: Looks like this is working. gotta tweek some stuff now. but my header is now resizing. thanks for the input.

Comment: my #dgwrap has a bkground image on there... but for some reason. if I put the height and width with MAX- the image wont show up...